# R, error in finding degree, closeness and betweenness

Tags: r, igraph, social-networking, sna

Trying to apply the common measures of centrality to a simple data set of non-directed like this:

[image]

It gives error:

```
Error in closeness(net, gmode = "graph") : unused argument (gmode = "graph")
```

When I removed the argument (gmode = "graph), it gives:

```
Error in degree(W) : Not a graph object
```

I have tried to use this lines to convert them, but still doesn't work:

```
W <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(df)
W <- graph_from_data_frame(df)
```

How can I correct them? thank you.

Here are the lines:

```
Bob <- c(0,1,0,0,0)
Kate <- c(0,0,0,1,0)
David <- c(0,0,0,1,0)
Jack <- c(0,0,1,0,0)
Peter <- c(0,1,0,0,1)
df <- data.frame(Bob, Kate, David, Jack, Peter)

library(igraph)

W <- data.frame(df)
net <- network(W)

net %v% 'vertex.names'

degree(W, gmode="graph")
closeness(net, gmode="graph")
betweenness(net, gmode="graph")
```

Add-on after this question is answered, in case it can help someone - to convert Excel format into a adjacency_matrix, use below lines.

```
df <- readxl::read_excel("spreadsheet.xlsx", sheet = "Sheet1")
W <- as.matrix(df)
W <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(W)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is somewhat mysterious, suggesting perhaps a use of of some other package? There is no such function `network` in `igraph`, functions `degree`, `closeness`, and `betweenness` don't have argument `gmode`. I believe the following is what you were after:

```
library(igraph)
# We are going to use graph_from_adjacency_matrix, so we need a matrix
# rather than a data frame
df <- cbind(Bob, Kate, David, Jack, Peter)

W <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(df)

V(W)$name
# [1] "Bob"   "Kate"  "David" "Jack"  "Peter"

degree(W)
#   Bob  Kate David  Jack Peter 
#     1     3     2     3     3 
closeness(W)
#        Bob       Kate      David       Jack      Peter 
# 0.05000000 0.08333333 0.11111111 0.16666667 0.05000000 
# Warning message:
# In closeness(W) :
#   At centrality.c:2784 :closeness centrality is not well-defined for disconnected graphs
betweenness(W)
#   Bob  Kate David  Jack Peter 
#     0     4     0     3     0
```

Answer (score 1):

The function degree exists both in igraph and sna package. However, gmode argument only exists in the sna package version of it. A basic solution for this can be  using `sna::degree(net, gmode="graph")` can be helpful for this issue.

Source:

degree {sna}      R Documentation

Compute the Degree Centrality Scores of Network Positions

Description
Degree takes one or more graphs (dat) and returns the degree centralities of positions (selected by nodes) within the graphs indicated by g. Depending on the specified mode, indegree, outdegree, or total (Freeman) degree will be returned; this function is compatible with centralization, and will return the theoretical maximum absolute deviation (from maximum) conditional on size (which is used by centralization to normalize the observed centralization score).

Usage

```
degree(dat, g=1, nodes=NULL, gmode="digraph", diag=FALSE,
    tmaxdev=FALSE, cmode="freeman", rescale=FALSE, ignore.eval=FALSE)
```